# What is the zero for string?

Tags: string, go

```
func NewKey(c appengine.Context, kind, stringID string, intID int64, parent *Key) *Key
```

The documentation says :

> NewKey creates a new key. kind cannot be empty. Either one or both of
>   stringID and intID must be **zero**. If both are zero, the key
>   returned is incomplete. parent must either be a complete key or nil.

What is the zero for string?

I tried `0` and `nil`, and I got errors like:

```
cannot use nil as type string in function argument
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

That's `""` :

```
var s string
fmt.Println(s=="") // prints "true"
```

A string cannot be nil (but a `*string` can).

You can simply test

```
if stringId=="" {
```

To pass a zero string in `stringID`, use

```
k := NewKey(c, "kind", "", 0, p)
```

From [the specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) :

> When memory is allocated to store a value, either through a
>   declaration or a call of make or new, and no explicit initialization
>   is provided, the memory is given a default initialization. Each
>   element of such a value is set to the zero value for its type: false
>   for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, **"" for strings**, and nil
>   for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

Comment: A simple test for a zero value string and *string: var s string ; fmt.Println(s == "", *new(*string) == nil)

Answer (score 0):

in this case empty string, or you can use NewIncompleteKey()